# Add Microsoft.Extensions.Logging to .NETStandard project without assuming Dependency Injection available

Tags: c#, logging, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I want to support logging in my **.NETStandard** project that will be consumed by a .NET Core Console or Web Client. However I don't want to presume the client uses a constructor that requires a ILogger dependency in the constructor of the classes I wish to log from.

If the logger does not exist, I basically don't want to fail because of this.

So my question is how can I reference ILogger in my code without passing it to the constructor?

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyApp
{
  public class MyClass
  {
     //slf4net logger implementation 
     private static readonly slf4net.ILogger _slf4netLogger = slf4net.LoggerFactory.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));

     //Microsoft.Extensions.Logging???
     private static readonly ILogger<MyClass> _logger = ???

     public MyClass()
     {
        //Constructor empty
     }

     public void MyMethod()
     {
        //slf4net logger works like this
        _slf4netLogger.Trace("This got logged");

        //this won't work because the logger was never passed from the constructor
        _logger.LogInformation("A message for the log if one is listening");
     }
   }
}
```

## references:

- https://github.com/ef-labs/slf4net
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging?tabs=aspnetcore2x

It seems like I'm not alone with my frustration here

> **Accessing the Logging API Outside of a MVC Controller**
>
> OK, so this is where the new logging API quickly becomes a nightmare.
>   - https://stackify.com/net-core-loggerfactory-use-correctly/

Comment: Add a property to the class for the microsoft version of the ILogger.  I dont think slf4net uses the same ILogger.  Add a logging methods to the class (one for error, trace, loginformation, etc..).    In the methods if the microsoft ILogger is not null use that otherwise try and get the slf4net ILogger.

Comment: Thanks @KenTucker, I've updated the property for slf4netLogger in the question to make it easier to separate. I ideally want to remove all references to slf4net and only support the Microsoft version. I don't know what property to add because that is what my question addresses. Adding all possible logging types to the class will create a nasty pattern across my application. Maybe I could have two constructors though with a NOOP log implementation in another class, the same as slf4net does it: 
https://github.com/ef-labs/slf4net/blob/develop/src/slf4net/NOPLogger.cs